# Comparing PhoneGap and HTML5 APIs for geolocation and online status

Tags: html, cordova

I'm developing an mobile apps using PhoneGap 2.7. I require the geolocation and network status APIs only. I found that those APIs are available from HTML5 directly using navigator.gelocation and navigator.onLine. So, should I use the PhoneGap APIs? What're their difference?

Comment: what kind of app you are going to build? hybrid web app Or usual web app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can read on the [docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation)

> This API is based on the W3C Geolocation API Specification, and only executes on devices that don't already provide an implementation.

it is used to provide backward compatibility if the device does not natively support the method.

---

`navigator.geolocation` is a standard which was introduced with HTML5. If you try `navigator.geolocation` on browsers which don't support this new standard you will receive `undefined`. PhoneGap now helps you and simulates `navigator.geolocation` for such (old) browsers. The api is [exactly the same](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) as in the W3C specification. If the browser supports the HTML5 geolocation api PhoneGap simply pipes it through. If not PhoneGap makes sure you can still use it (backward compatibility for unsupported devices). Request permissions on the device to use the geolocation service (like described on the PhoneGap docs) and stop worrying, PhoneGap's doing the rest.

See [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=geolocation) for browsers supporting the geolocation standard.

Comment: I don't understand it and could you explain in more detail. As far as I know, the geolocation API is supported on Android 2.0+ and iOS 3.0+. Do you mean the PhoneGap API is for handling OS older than these versions? Moreover, what's the backward compatibility that you mean?

Comment: But does that mean I am seeing ugly HTML request prompt (I am fine with "App wants to use your location") because Cordova doesn't override HTML5? How can I force Cordova to override it and NOT use HTML5 implementation. I am talking about native packaged app.